# Run command in Windows command prompt from anywhere

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10

In Linux we would do the following:

```
$ /var/mongodb/bin/mongod
```

I'm trying to do the following in windows but it just isn't working:

```
C:\>C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongodb --dbpath \var\data
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Also tried:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongodb" --dbpath \var\data
'"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongodb"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: @SeanClt Tried, still not working :/

Comment: @SeanClt Ah, it did work, the command is mongod not mongodb, post an answer I'll accept!

Comment: Does it work if you run the command from the directory there the executable exists? If not, then there may be more than a path issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there are spaces in the path it needs to be added between quotes

C:>"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod" --dbpath \var\data

Normally if you are getting an error like "'C:\Program' is not recognized " it's path issue because windows is not liking the space between Program and Files

One way to avoid this type of mistake can be done by writing the command on command prompt and using TAB key to auto complete. meaning you type C:\Program then hit TAB and it will auto complete with quote and you can do it for the rest of the path too by typing \ this avoid spelling mistakes and you can easily make sure the files do exist

Comment: @CharlieRB It was `mongod` not `mongodb`, he also helped with the quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly, you want to run a command prompt from a specific folder?

To do that, all you do is hold down the SHIFT key in the folder you want your command prompt to open to, right-click and select "Open command window here". You don't have to type anything

Comment: I understand what your saying, but I'm from linux so I'm more a terminal person. Also I write scripts sometimes and would like the scripts to be able to run the correct command wherever the file is!